# WKWebView redirection issue compared to UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, xcode7, wkwebview

I am updating a `UIWebView` to `wkWebView` for the first time,
There are a few URLs which I was using with `UIWebView` that are not working properly with `wkWebView`.

For Example:
There is a log-in URL, which, in a `UIWebView', once I logged in, would automatically redirect me to the detail page.

With `wkWebView`, however, logging in simply reloads the log-in page.

I tried a lot but unable to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing the same issues. Since doing a release build for testing. Some users can redirect and some can't. Is it possible there is a device permission or security setting that prevents redirects?

Comment: I dont think so, I tried almost every scenario but unable to get the result.